# Does T[keyof T] work like the distributive conditional type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand this example from the [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) section:

> Conditional types are particularly useful when combined with mapped
> types:
>
> ```
> type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
>   [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never;
> }[keyof T];
> ```

The usage of the **index access** operator is not clear for me, in this example.
Here is the simplest example which uses the same idea (as far as I can understand):

```
type Foo = {
    prop1: never;
    prop2: never
    method1: "method1";
    method2: "method2";
}

type FunctionPropertyNames = Foo[keyof Foo] // "method1" | "method2"
```

So, my question: is such usage of index access operator just a specific case of the distributive conditional type? Because it looks like result type is the union of all applications of T[K] where `never` is filtered because ["`never` is the empty union"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31751#issuecomment-498526919)

---

**Update.** I will try to formulate this question more precisely:
TS Handbook describes what is the syntax for mapped types, and for conditional types.
However, I did not find any description of this form of the type definition:

```
type Keys = 'name1' | 'name2' | 'name3'
type Foo = Bar[Keys]
```

or, more realistic:

```
type Foo = Bar[keyof Bar]
```

It looks like some kind of mapping, but it also provides filtering, in the case when Keys contains `never`. So my question was more about if there any precise description of this feature of the TS type system.

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific usage that is powerful when it comes to filter the properties of an object/class based on the type of the attributes. This [article](https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/) explains it really well how it is convenient to filter a union of classes based on a method they implement or not (see section `Refining unions with distributive conditional types` of the article).

## Other usage

As you said, the advantage of this usage of index access operator helps to remove irrevlevant types from a union but it has other advantages like to change a type based on certain conditions.

Here is an example:

```
type SchemaType<T> = {
  [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | Types.ObjectId
    | Client
    | Doer
    | Mission
    | Date
    | Array<any>
    ? SchemaDefinition['']
    : SchemaType<T[k]>;
};
```

This is a `type` I use to type my mongoose documents.

I have a typescript `interface` that defines what a `User` is and a `document` that describes the document in mongoDb.

What I wanted is to have the `document` implement the same hierarchy as the `interface`.

For example, if the `User` has the structure:

```
interface User {
  id: Types.ObjectId;
  profile: {
    first_name: string;
  }
}
```

I wanted the `document` to enforce the same one and be typesafe:

```
const schema: SchemaType<User> = {
  id: { type: Types.ObjectId },
  profile: {
    first_name: { type: String, default: '' },
  },
};
```

That's what does the `SchemaType` with the index access operator. If the property is considered a leaf type (like `id` and `first_name` are), then it must be typed as a `SchemaDefinition` in the document. If it's an object, then it must be typed as it is in the `interface` (that's what `SchemaType<T[k]>` does).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the link to the article. I read it yesterday, it contains some really good explanations. However, I'm not sure, that it answers my question. I will try to update it and formulate it more clearly.